# Setting abbrev-mode variables before enabling abbrev-mode

Tags: abbrev

Have done some tests with `abbrev-mode` variables.  I can set `global-abbrev-table` even when `abbrev-mode` has not been enabled yet with a hook or with `(abbrev-mode 1)`.  How does this happen?

Comment: Setting a variable and using it (or not) are two separate activities. There is no mystery here, so I think you are overthinking things.

Comment: The question asks about when do variables get defined for `abbrev-mode`.  Looks like it is built-in and becomes available as soon as emacs gets launched.  When I make my own configurations, I have to perform `require` first, which I do not see that happening with `abbrev-mode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Too long for a comment]

"The question asks about when do variables get defined for abbrev-mode."

The answer is "whenever they are defined". When you first start Emacs, there is a `global-abbrev-table` that is empty (there are many other abbrev tables as well but I just discuss the global one for simplicity). If you have a saved `abbrev_defs` file from a previous session, Emacs will load that and fill in entries into `global-abbrev-table`. If you want to, you can add more entries in this session. All this time, the variable exists and has some value, but it is not used. When you turn `abbrev-mode` on, then the variable will be used: every time you finish a word, it will be looked up in the table and if found, it will be replaced by its definition. If you turn `abbrev-mode` off, the variable is still around, holding whatever value it had, but now every word you type is *NOT* looked up and therefore *NOT* replaced by its definition. The definition still exists though (unless you delete it). Whether the mode is on or off, you can add more definitions to the table. But they will only be used if the mode is on. Finally, when you exit Emacs, the abbrev tables (not just the global one) will be saved in your `abbrev_defs` file so that the process can be repeated next time you start Emacs.

The "Abbrev Concepts" section of the Emacs Reference manual says:

> You can define abbrevs interactively during the editing session,
> irrespective of whether Abbrev mode is enabled.  You can also save lists
> of abbrev definitions in files, which you can then reload for use in
> later sessions.

You can get to it with `C-h i g(emacs) RET m abbrev concepts`.

For saving abbrevs, see `C-h i g(emacs) RET m saving abbrevs`. Emacs looks for the file where the abbrevs are stored when it starts up and loads it if found. The file name is the value of the variable `abbrev-file-name`.

I hope that's clear enough.

Comment: All abbrev functions and variables would get loaded when one starts emacs.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: `abbrev.el[c]`  is "dumped" when the Emacs binary is created, so it's part of Emacs to begin with. It defines (empty) `global-abbrev-table` (and others). Then as Emacs starts running, it calls a function `command-line` which parses the command line and does a *ton* of iniitialization, among which is the loading of any saved abbrev file (as described in the answer). By the time that Emacs is ready and waiting for you to say something, all of this has been done.